# Regex index selection or path selection

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string,

\Text1\partT1\PartT1_OP30_3_ExtraInfo.nc

I can get the Text1 part, using (?<=\)([a-zA-Z0-9\s-='!+_]+)(?=\)

However, I want to also get the second folder "partT1".

But I can't seem to figure out how to get it.  From the regex tool I'm using, I can see the value has an index of 1, how do I get to this, the string value of the folders will be different each time.
[image]

Comment: Are you writing the code in C#?

Comment: It's a C# program that takes 4 different regular expressions to identify some data for populating a DB.
I doesn't seem possible to me to get different bits of data from a different folder, e.g. folder1=feild1 in the DB, but the developer ensures me this is possible and yet won't help.

Comment: Then just get all matches, `var AllMatches = Regex.Matches(text, regex).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToList();`, then you can access each as you wish.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the code, however I think there may be a pattern I can use.
My string is "INT-I200\\114122687\\Route 10196\\OP80\\PartT1_OP30_3_ExtraInfo.nc"
If I use (Route )([a-zA-Z0-9-='!+_]) I can get the text "Route", but what I want to do is get the data before it, e.g. "114122687".
Is that possible?

Comment: Can you share the code? If you can use groups and access their values, then there is a way. Else, there is none.

Comment: Do you always want to match the second part of the path?

Comment: Yes.  I always want the second value, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This expression get the string 114122687 from \INT-I200\114122687\Route 10196\OP80\file.txt

(?<=\.*\)\d+

The \d matches any decimal digit. Equivalent to \p{Nd} for Unicode and [0-9] for non-Unicode, ECMAScript behaviour.